# Can I carry on my Mercurail Repository, which started on Windows, on Linux ubuntu?

Tags: mercurial, repository

I had a Mercurial Repository on Windows and I want to carry on my work in the same Repository on Linux ubuntu is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clone or copy your repository to Linux and continue working.

As long as you install Mercurial on your Ubuntu installation then you can continue working just fine.

You need to decide whether you want to work on the repository on both platforms though because that would require you to be able to push or pull between your two platforms, or possibly that you should place a clone of the repository somewhere more central, like [Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org), and push and pull on both your platforms.